# mount-defaults does not mount

Tags: debootstrap

I am trying to setup an chroot image of `Precise 12.04` under `Lucid 10.04`. The process seemed to be fine, but when I do `schroot -c precise -u root` I don't see anything under /home of the chroot image. This means the /home is not mounted.

My mount-defaults content:

```
cat /etc/schroot/mount-defaults 
# mount.defaults: static file system information for chroots.
# Note that the mount point will be prefixed by the chroot path
# (CHROOT_PATH)
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>   <dump>  <pass>
proc        /proc       proc    defaults    0   0
#procbususb      /proc/bus/usb   usbfs   defaults        0       0
#/dev            /dev            none    rw,bind         0       0
/dev/pts    /dev/pts    none    rw,bind     0   0
/dev/shm    /dev/shm    none    rw,bind     0   0
/home       /home       none    rw,bind     0   0
/tmp        /tmp        none    rw,bind     0   0
```

My host /home is a mount to a separate partition. 
How do I get /home or any external directory to mount on my chroot image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to put `type=directory` in the image definition under `/etc/schroot/schroot.conf`. See `man schroot.conf` for more information.